# Vertical flyout menu left of main content

Tags: html, css

My current HTML/CSS setup places the leftmenu and the main in a container, but the main div appears UNDER the menu. As soon as I use float:left; on the navigation, the navigation becomes a horizontal menu. How do I have the leftmenu and the main content on the same horizontal level?

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CMAP Playground 4</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
            <ul class="headernav">
                <li><a class="headernav" href="#" title="Main website">CMAP</a></li>
                <li><a class="headernav" href="#" title="SharePoint Server">SharePoint</a></li>
                <li><a class="headernav" href="#" title="Wiki Pages">Wiki</a></li>
                <li><a class="headernav" href="#" title="MetroPulse">Metropulse</a></li>
            </ul>

        <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>

<div id="container">

    <div id="leftmenuwrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="IT Homepage">IT Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Our Services">Services</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Product 1">Product 1</a>    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Product 2">Product 2</a></li>
                </ul><li>
            <li><a href="#" title="About IT">About IT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="The IT Index">IT A-Z Index</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Current News">Hot Topics</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div class="rightmenu">
        Print this page!
</div>

    <div class="main">
        <h1>
            Welcome to CMAP Intranet
        </h1>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p></br>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p></br>
</div>

    <div class="footer">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="footernav" href="#" title="Get connected">Get Connected</a></li>
            <li><a class="footernav" href="#" title="IT Services">IT Services</a></li>
            <li><a class="footernav" href="#" title="About IT">About IT</a></li>
            <li><a class="footernav" href="#" title="CMAP website">CMAP</a></li>
            <li><a class="footernav" href="#" title="SharePoint Server">SharePoint</a></li>
            <li><a class="footernav" href="#" title="Wiki page">Wiki</a></li>
            <li><a class="footernav" href="#" title="Metropulse">Metropulse</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#container {
  height:auto;
    border:1px solid green;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  #leftmenuwrapper ul, #leftmenuwrapper ul li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
  }

  #leftmenuwrapper ul li {
      background-color:#7f95db;
      border-bottom:solid 1px white;
      width:140px;
      display: block;
  }

  #leftmenuwrapper ul li:hover {
      background-color: #6679e9;
      position: relative;
  }

  #leftmenuwrapper ul li a {
      padding: 5px 15px;
      color: #FFF;
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
  }

  #leftmenuwrapper ul li ul {
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
  }

  #leftmenuwrapper ul li:hover ul {
      left: 140px;
      top: 0px;
      display: block;
  }

  #leftmenuwrapper ul li ul li{
      background-color:#cae25a;
  }

      .main {
          width: 60%;
          margin: 0 10em 0 10em;
          padding: 0 10px;
          display: inline-block;
      }
```

Comment: Omg. Send me the entire html and css file and I'll help you from start.. ;) erik@welcom.se

Comment: Appreciate the help. Will do that once I get out of lecture. Thanks!